# How can I enhance the empty state for the hooks view in my UI form

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, react-hook-form

As I am trying to enhance the empty state for the hooks view in my UI form where there are no hooks to display in the view but I am trying to expect to see something say other than  "No items for search term" in the behavior. I am a bit confused about what logic can I add to enhance the empty state.

**Here is my code:**

```
export default class ListHooks extends Component {
  handleCreateHook = () => {
    this.props.history.push('/hooks/create');
  };

  handleHookSearchSubmit = hookSearch => {
    const query = parse(window.location.search.slice(1));

    this.props.history.push({
      search: stringify({
        ...query,
        search: hookSearch,
      }),
    });
  };

  render() {
    const {
      classes,
      description,
      data: { loading, error, hookGroups },
    } = this.props;
    const query = qs.parse(this.props.location.search.slice(1));
    const hookSearch = query.search;
    const tree = hookGroups
      ? hookGroups.map(group => ({
          value: group.hookGroupId,
          nodes: group.hooks.map(hook => ({
            value: hook.hookId,
            href: `/hooks/${group.hookGroupId}/${encodeURIComponent(
              hook.hookId
            )}`,
          })),
        }))
      : [];

    return (
      <Dashboard
        title="Hooks"
        helpView={<HelpView description={description} />}
        search={
          <Search
            placeholder="Hook contains"
            defaultValue={hookSearch}
            onSubmit={this.handleHookSearchSubmit}
          />
        }>
        {!hookGroups && loading && <Spinner loading />}
        <ErrorPanel fixed error={error} />
        {hookGroups && (
          <MuiTreeView
            // key is necessary to expand the list of hook when searching
            key={hookSearch}
            defaultExpanded={Boolean(hookSearch)}
            listItemProps={{ color: classes.listItemProps }}
            searchTerm={hookSearch || null}
            softSearch
            tree={tree}
            onEmptySearch={
              <Typography variant="subtitle1">
                No items for search term {hookSearch}
              </Typography>
            }
            Link={Link}
          />
        )}
        <Button
          spanProps={{ className: classes.actionButton }}
          tooltipProps={{ title: 'Create Hook' }}
          color="secondary"
          variant="round"
          onClick={this.handleCreateHook}>
          <PlusIcon />
        </Button>
      </Dashboard>
    );
  }
}
```